# multiple rdp connections?

Tags: windows, gui, remote, rdp

I've set up a physical box with ubuntu, for learning purposes. Currently, I am able to remote into it by using NX and the native VNC client on my mac. How can I go about allowing remote connections (w/ GUI, not SSH) to each individual user's account on the Ubuntu machine like you would on a Windows box?